# node.js ssh2 error: received data for nonexistent channel 0

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a little module in node to quickly deploy a meteor app to a custom server;
it just uses scp to send the package to the server and then connect by ssh (using npm ssh2 module) and executes some commands to unpack, install and launch the app;

I only have one issue that pops up sometimes:

```
Error: Disconnected by host (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Received data for nonexistent channel 0.
```

I can't understand why (and why only sometimes it occurs); the only thing I know is that when it happens, it's always at the same line: you can see it here

https://github.com/Cerealkillerway/MeteorDeploy

At file lib/deploy.js at line 205;
it's just a ssh.exec command and I'm not been able to reproduce this behaviour whenever I want;

does someone know what's wrong here?

**--- UPDATE ---**

This is the log I get when the error occurs:

```
remove app tar file...
DEBUG: Connection: Sending CHANNEL_OPEN
DEBUG: Parser: STATE_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 16)
DEBUG: Parser: STATE_PACKET
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:60,padLen:6,remainLen:48
DEBUG: Parser: STATE_PACKETDATA
DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
DEBUG: Parser: hmacSize:16
DEBUG: Parser: STATE_PACKETDATAVERIFY
DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
DEBUG: Parser: STATE_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: DISCONNECT

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Disconnected by host (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Received data for nonexistent channel 1.
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor-deploy-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Connection.js:187:11)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Parser.parsePacket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor-deploy-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Parser.js:436:10)
    at Parser.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor-deploy-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Parser.js:249:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor-deploy-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Connection.js:536:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
```

Comment: Can you try the [master branch](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/) and let me know if that resolves your problem?

Comment: Yes, using master branch it seems to work every time; until now I've not been able to see errors again

Comment: update: using it more times, i've started to receive sometimes the error: Error: Disconnected by host (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Received data for nonexistent channel 1.

Comment: like the previous error, I can't understand the cause; executing the script again immediatly after one failure, usually works again

Comment: Can you set `debug: console.log` in your ssh2 connection config and post a link to the output for the session that sees the error?

Comment: Tried 10 times without seeing the error again; I'll let the debug option enabled and let you know as soon as the error will popup again...

Comment: Can you post more of the log before the error? CHANNEL_OPEN should not be triggering this error. Also, can you try the HEAD of the [rewrite branch](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/tree/rewrite) and let me know if the problem still exists there?

Comment: sure, I will try and let you know; as I said it's not a very frequent error, it happens only sometimes; don't sure of this, but maybe it's related to a moment of slow connection speed?